# Test in which function a callback is executed

Tags: javascript, function, callback, prototype

I'm trying to test in which function this callback function in executed. It should return a boolean value.
I hope you know what I mean.

Here the code example:

```
function test(par, callback) {
  // ...
  if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
    callback.call(this);
  }

}

test("par", function() {
  console.log("Test if in function test: " + "<if this is in function test>");
});
```

Is this similar to **instanceof**?

Comment: What you are asking about has nothing to do with **instanceof**.  Perhaps what you're looking for is the deprecated `arguments.caller`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller

Comment: my mind is recursively looping on this 8-/ ... arent you actually in need of checking a call stack? that`s on developer tools in browsers

Comment: A non-standard way to do it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a non-standard way of doing it since the removal of `arguments.caller`

```js
function test(par, callback) {
  // ...
  if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
    callback.call(this);
  }

}

test("par", function cb() {
  var isTestCaller = cb.caller === test;
  console.log("Test if in function test: " + isTestCaller);
});
```

Another possible way doing it through error stacks (still non-standard):

```js
var checkCaller = function(fnName) {
  var e = new Error();
  var caller = e.stack.split('\n')[2].trim().split(' ')[1];
  return caller === fnName;
}

function wrapper(){
  console.log(checkCaller('wrapper'));
}

wrapper();
```

Comment: Cool it works, but is this also possible without giving the function a name? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've included another possible way, but I'm unsure of how well it will behave across browsers (at least `function.caller` is available on common browsers)

Comment: You could also use `arguments.callee` to get to the anonymous function `caller`. Not possible on strict mode though.